# Unable to resolve service for type 'ICitaService' while attempting to activate 'CitaController'

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

497

I created an API and use Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern to inject a Service to my controller. However, I am getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CitaGlamApi.CitaGlam.Application.Services.ICitaService' while attempting to activate 'CitaGlamApi.Controllers.CitaController'.

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddScoped\<ICitaService, CitaService\>();
...
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class CitaController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICitaService _citaService;

        public CitaController(ICitaService citaService)
        {
            _citaService = citaService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(citaService));
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
public class CitaRepository : IRepository<Cita>
```

Comment: Assuming CitaService uses IRepository. Has DI been set up for this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Service Registration: Ensure that you have registered the `ICitaService` and its implementation `(CitaService)` correctly in your `Startup.cs` file using `services.AddScoped<ICitaService, CitaService>()`. The `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` should look like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICitaService, CitaService>();
    // Add other services and configurations
}
```

Try this and it should work. I am not very familiar with `IRepository` hope this gets what you need!